# How can I create a function which contains local_mock()?

Tags: r, mocking, testthat

Currently I am working on several UnitTests and my tests also contain mocking.
In order to "pass" on functions part of my function, I am applying the local_mock() function from the testthat package.

However, there are several functions on which the local_mock function needs to be applied.
They have a different structure, but same number of arguments.

Hence, I created a function as following:

```
.apply_local_mock = function(Function, File){
   local_mock(Function = function(Argument1, Argument2, Argument3) {
      result = .readCsv(file.path(targetPath, "Input", paste(File))) %>%
      return(result)
   })
}
```

An example of two functions to which local_mock will be applied to:

```
CalcProfitability <- function(IncomeStatement, BalanceSheet, Months){
  result = (12/Months) * (IncomeStatement / BalanceSheet)
  return(result)
}
```

```
CalcDiffDivByPl <- function(BalanceSheetCY, BalanceSheetPY, IncomeStatement){
  result = (BalanceSheetCY - BalanceSheetPY) / IncomeStatement
  return(result)
}
```

So the mocking test code looks as following:

```
.apply_local_mock(CalcProfitability,"CalcProfitability.csv")
.apply_local_mock(CalcDiffDivByPl ,"CalcDiffDivByPl.csv")
```

But I am receiving the following error:

```
Error: Function FunctionName not found in environment testthat.
```

Can anyone please advise how to include local_mock() function in a new function?